# android infinite Toast message using CountDownTimer

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I'm trying to display an infinite Toast message. As I understand this is not possible regularly, so I'm using CountDownTimer. this is where i'm stuck:

```
   public void onClick(View view) {


            int toastDurationInMilliSeconds = 500000;
            toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "aa", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            CountDownTimer toastCountDown;
            toastCountDown = new CountDownTimer(toastDurationInMilliSeconds, 5000){
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
                    toast.show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    toast.show();
                }

            };

            toast.show();
            toastCountDown.start();

        }`
```

This currently gets me a toast message that disappears for a second, then comes back
**My question:** how do i make it appear infinite?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact reason you want to show a toast message, but I'm assuming you're trying to give feedback to a user. If that's the case, I suggest to give [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html) a try.

```
Snackbar mySnackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.myCoordinatorLayout),
                                 "Your text here", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
mySnackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `onTick()` method is called every 5000 milliseconds i.e. every 5 seconds, while `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` is shown for 3500 milliseconds.
[Android Source | PhoneWindowManager.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/policy/PhoneWindowManager.java)
[Android Source | NotificationManagerService.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java)
So, you should initialise your `CountDownTimer` as:

```
CountDownTimer toastCountDown;
toastCountDown = new CountDownTimer(toastDurationInMilliSeconds, 3500)
```

*Since user can't cancel `Toast` manually and it will appear even when your app goes into background, it can be annoying and a bad user experience to show `Toast` for such long time.*
I would also suggest you to use `Snackbar` with indefinite length, as mentioned in [other answer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java).

**Edit: Working code**

```
public void onClick(View view) {


        int toastDurationInMilliSeconds = 500000;
        toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "aa", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        CountDownTimer toastCountDown;
        toastCountDown = new CountDownTimer(toastDurationInMilliSeconds, 3400){
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
                toast.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                //toast.show();
            }

        };

        //toast.show();
        toastCountDown.start();

    }`
```

Comment: Snackbar isn't an option for me sadly since my purpose is different than to just display a feedback to the user. Changing milliseconds doesn't change anything for some reason

Comment: Try changing milliseconds to 3000 or less. It should work.

Comment: None of it worked, best I get is a on and off toast with 1 second delays

Comment: look here: https://imgur.com/a/CrKjI and see the seconds past in status bar. I have called `toast.show()` only inside `onTick()`, see edit.